# How to share a Microsoft access token obtained via a middleware node.js server to the client for a Sharepoint Add-ins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to obtain an access token to make API requests with the Microsoft Graph API, so that I'm able to access OneDrive files by clicking a button in the sharepoint ribbon. I've never done it, and I may be following the wrong path.

As of now, on my client, I'm calling this function to redirect my sharepoint page to my server to start the authentication

```
function Authenticate() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:44368/";
    return
}
```

And then, on the server-side, I obtain an authorization code, and then obtain an access Token that I try to share with the client in the URL, but it's too long and I don't know what else to try. Here's the server side:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // Redirect to the Azure AD authorization endpoint to start the OAuth flow
    const authParams = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "openid profile offline_access files.read user.read",
        // Add any additional parameters as needed
    });

    const authUrl = `${authorizationUrl}?${authParams}`;
    res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code;

    if (!code) {
        return res.status(400).send("Authorization code not found in the callback.");
    }

    try {
        // Exchange the authorization code for an access token
        const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: "openid profile offline_access",
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            client_secret: clientSecret,
        }));

        const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
        const refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;


        // Redirect the user to a success page or your app's main page
        if (!accessToken) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Access token not found in the query parameters." });
        }

        res.redirect(`https://my-Sharepoint-site/Sites/dev/PT/Pages/ExploreOneDrive.aspx?accessToken=${accessToken}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during token exchange:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error during token exchange.");
    }
});
```

What should I do to send the token to the client, and am I doing something wrong?
Thanks you.

Comment: Did you fixed your error?